# of areas involved with patients’ care - or patients care?

Tags: grammar, british-english

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User’s/Users’/Users Group](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76593/users-users-users-group)

What would be the correct way with UK English spelling:

patients' care or patients care?

I have terrible search skills, I could not find an appropriate answer (did not know how to search for these "'s" or "s'" differences).

Comment: You do need to know what to search for. Here's one, which also links to another. [User’s/Users’/Users Group](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76593/users-users-users-group)

Comment: By going to that link I found another one that was really useful: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36657/users-guide-vs-users-guide - check Robusto's and Mr. Shiny and New 安宇's reply - it helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be a whole lot of consensus on this but this link (Andrew provided) was useful: [User’s Guide vs Users’ Guide](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36657/users-guide-vs-users-guide)

> User's guide: A guide belonging to one user.
>
> Users' guide: A guide belonging to all the users.

And:

> The difference is this: s' is used for plural possessive; 's is used for singular possessive; s' can also be used at the end of proper names that end in s to indicate the possessive without adding the extra s.

Answer (score 0):

You would find both in the UK, but the apostrophe is disappearing in such cases and, it must be said, it is no great loss.

Comment: I think just saying “patient care” is becoming the norm in many of these situations.