# "student list" vs "students list"?

Tags: american-english

What is more accurate to say when writing a noun before a list?
"student list" or "students list"
(also "student group" vs "students group")

Comment: Related: [User’s/Users’/Users Group](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76593/users-users-users-group)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a difference between US and UK English - and maybe not, but as a Brit, I'd incline towards "student list". After all, the plural is implied by "list" isn't it?

Comment: I don't think _passengers list_ would be a common usage at either end of the flight.