# “Members’ gallery” vs. “members gallery”

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, apostrophe

What would I use when setting up a gallery for many members to submit to?

I am thinking, *Members’ Gallery*, as it is a gallery belonging to all the members, but I frequently see the use of just *Members Gallery*.

Comment: the above is not very enlightening if that was my issue nor is it my issue, however I can see their similarities so I can understand your thinking on the possible duplicate

Comment: As well as that question, there's [another one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76593/user-s-users-users-group) which is more directly similar, but that's also marked as a duplicate of the User's Guide one. You are welcome to enhance this question to explain how earlier questions do not cover it.

Comment: I don't see how it's a duplicate at all. The other question is about choosing between singular possessive and plural possessive. This question is about choosing between plural possessive and simple plural.

Comment: If I tried to use the other question to answer my own I would come up none the wiser. In fact I did look at it and try to use it to answer my own question because the duplicate possibility came up before I had any answers on my question. I failed to use that information to deduce the answer to my question as they focus on entirely different though not dissimilar points

Answer (score 0):

A "members' gallery" is a gallery *belonging to* the members. A "members gallery" is a gallery *of* the members.

If all the pictures in your gallery are *of* your members, then you've got yourself a "members gallery". If the gallery contains pictures *by* or *for* your members, then you're offering your members a gallery: it's your *members' gallery*.

For reference, here's a picture of [Madam Tussaud's Presidents Gallery](http://www.madametussauds.com/Washington/PlanYourVisit/ExploreMadameTussaudsDC/PresidentsGallery.aspx) (note: no apostrophe). It contains lifelike wax figures of all 44 US presidents; but I doubt a single US president has ever visited it:

[image: Three US presidents in Madam Tussaud's Presidents Gallery]

Comment: thank you, that cleared it up in my mind quite nicely, I am definitely making a members' gallery here.

Answer (score 0):

*Members' Gallery* is preferable, in that it conveys the meaning of the phrase more exactly: it correctly identifies the members, plural, as possessing the gallery, in the linguistic sense. However, if the non-possessive *members* is thought of as a simple noun modifier, then *members gallery* can also be acceptable, just as *member gallery* would be.

My impression is that a construction like *members gallery* would be more acceptable in the UK, with its recent campaign against the [greengrocer's apostrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Superfluous_apostrophes_.28.22greengrocers.27_apostrophes.22.29). In the US, it would be more likely to be flagged as an error by prescriptivist grammar pedants; linguistic descriptivists (such as most of the higher-rep users here) probably wouldn't have a problem with it, although some might consider it more awkward than the alternative.

Comment: interesting, didn't know about the greengrocer's apostrophe, I definitely like to get my apostrophe usage correct.