# How do you write "other users passwords"?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Should I write "You are not authorised to change other users passwords" or "You are not authorised to change other user's password"? Which is correct?

Comment: It's actually *other users' passwords* (possessive plural). See [a related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189026/members-gallery-vs-members-gallery) and others linked from there and in the "apostrophe" tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Other users* is plural. In this sentence, it needs to be possessive. The correct form would be

> You are not authorised to change other *users'* passwords.

If it were singular, it would be *another user's password*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good point. See edit.

Comment: @bib Congratulations: your answer was post 200000 on this site!

Comment: @chiastic-security Gee, I thought I had *personally* made 200,000 posts on this site.