# Users wrists or user's wrists - addressing all wrists of users

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

I am launching new wearable software company with motto: **Get your service on users wrists** and I am not sure if it should be users or user's.

By the motto, I want to tell that you can get your service to wrists of all your users. What is the correct way to write this?

Also, company name is **WearSoft** - is it valid for UK or USA or there is some hidden meaning which make this name inappropriate?

Thank, Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should actually be "users' wrists", since this is a plural possessive: https://www.scribendi.com/advice/how_to_use_plural_possessives_properly.en.html

Comment: Hmm, I thought this wasn't right because those wrists doesn't belong to everybody, like in linked example with kittens' toy.. This doesn't make difference?

Comment: Or else, according to this post https://english.stackexchange.com/a/189027/324375 I understand that proper meaning should be wrists of users and than the correct sentence should be users wrists, correct?

Comment: You (Jan Capek) have misunderstood the other answer that you cite. It means "wrists belonging to users" hence Rawan Moukalled's answer is right.

Comment: ah, ok. Thanks to both. And do you by any change see any problem to have brand called WearSoft? How does it sound to born British? I don't want to find out months later on meeting with British client that the name is funny or something. :)