# Young Surveyors Network or Young Surveyor Network?

Tags: compounds, attributive-nouns

I'm a surveyor and we are currently setting up our network. However, there seems to be a disagreement on the proper name of the group. The group is composed of young surveyors under the age of 35, hence the name **Young Surveyors Network**. However, somebody in the group has challenged it and has asserted that it should be **Young Surveyor Network**. Personally I think the original name is just fine but I'd prefer more ammunition *wink wink*

Can somebody resolve this issue? Should it be **Young Surveyors Network** or **Young Surveyor Network**? Or does it need to take an apostrophe and be **Young Surveyors' Network**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Closely related (Yes, really!) [Opposite of the greengrocer's apostrophe](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59425/is-there-a-term-for-the-opposite-of-the-greengrocer-s-apostrophe)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! Sorry for the late response. Had trouble with the internet connection :)

Answer (score 2):

It's for young surveyors, right? There's more than one of them?

Therefore it should be *Young Surveyors' Network*.

Comment: Or _Young Surveyors Network_...a network of young surveyors, as opposed to a network _belonging to_ young surveyors.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's true... That kind of thing always looks wrong to me without the apostrophe, though. Although I'm beginning to see the apostrophe as looking fussy, too. I'm in danger of being assimilated!