# Where to use Womens and Women'S

Tags: grammatical-number

What is the difference between womens and Women's? where to use Womens and Women's?

Comment: "Women's" is the plural possessive of "woman."  "Womens" isn't a word.

Comment: Could you please say where you saw *womens*? The nouns *woman* and *women* should not be capitalized, unless it is the title of a book, or a proper noun such as [*Woman's Hour*](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b007qlvb)

Comment: [Related question about *mens*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112420/is-mens-a-valid-word) | [Related question about the "opposite of the greengrocer's apostrophe"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59425/is-there-a-term-for-the-opposite-of-the-greengrocers-apostrophe)

Comment: I saw at least 5 `womens` labels in Manchester shops and changing rooms in few days I spent there. But it could possibly be related to numerous emigrants living there.

Answer (score 4):

NEVER use "womens".

**Women** is the plural of *woman* , so there *cannot be a plural* of  **women**.

However, you will see this simple truth ignored everywhere you look:

- Womens Clothing Department
- Womens Restroom, Mens Restroom (signs on doors that say WOMENS and MENS) — wrong!!!
- Womens Issues, Womens Lib, etc.

Do not let these mistakes that other people make confuse or distract you. They are WRONG.  Usually these errors occur because people never learned the difference between *plurals and possessives*.

- **Woman** is *singular*.
  **Man** is *singular*.
- **Women** is *plural*.
  **Men** is *plural*.
- **Woman's** is a *singular possessive*.
  **Man's** is a *singular possessive*.
- **Women's** is a *plural possessive*.
  **Men's** is a *plural possessive*.
- **Womens** is not a word. **Mens** is not a word.

Learn the difference well, and don't believe what you see online or on signs!  A million people might get this wrong; that does not make them right.

Comment: But according to many on this site if people 'get it wrong a million times' it becomes *de facto* English - see postings *passim* on the use of *diagnose*. They will talk to you about *the etymological fallacy*. If there is an argument for it, why not apply it to grocers' apostrophes too! Personally I won't have any of it and support a corollary to the *etymological fallacy*.

Comment: Whatever. I get paid well to fix such garbage.